# Instant parallel hyperparameter scans with tensorflow and multiple GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I was thinking if it would be possible to use tensorflow  to train multiple small models on relatively small data in parallel (by placing them in an "independent" manner inside a single graph) on multiple GPU cards. This could be useful for fast hyperparameters scans.

My naive expectation was that as long as models and data fit the card memory there should be virtually no dependence of execution time on number of models.

I have used a system with 4 Tesla K80 cards to test this. Models were placed in a circular fashion on GPUs (first model - GPU0, second - GPU1, ..., fifth - GPU0 again). 4 independent copies of data were also placed on GPUs. I see the following dependence of the execution time with respect to the number of models:

[image]

From the step-like behaviour it looks that a single card is able to fit one model at time (when an additional model is placed on some card we go "step up" on the plot). Any idea what could I do to achieve desired performance (i.e. no dependence in the execution time on number of models fitted as long as card memory is not saturated)?

Some more info:

- nvidia-smi gives me 354 MB memory utilization per card (when model fitting run with gpu_options.allow_growth=True), so there is plenty of free memory left
- source code (adapted from tensorflow udacity course) avaliable on https://github.com/fruboes/parallel-small-models - same models are trained for simplicity

Comment: Training two models on a card is twice as much work.  So it makes sense to me that you get the step-up behavior as you add models to a single card.  I don't think it's reasonable to expect any processor to do twice as much (or three times as much) work in constant time.  The fact that there is still memory available on the card is pretty much irrelevant to the performance during training.

Comment: @RobertCrovella : thanks for a prompt answer! My (naive) expectation was that since models are rather small and simple they should train in parallel. During the training phase the GPU-Util reported by nvidia-smi is around 75% for each card. Do I understand correctly, that if it was significantly lower (e.g. 25%) I should see significant speedup for the setup described above (i.e. training multiple independent models inside a single graph) as expected? Or this is more subtle?

Comment: No, I don't think you can draw that conclusion.  There aren't any CNN type models that are small enough in TF that they would use such a small portion of GPU resources that there would be unused execution resources left over.  A GPU is not like a CPU in this respect.  Even "small jobs" on the GPU occupy the entire device.  The "job size" you would have to have in order to not occupy the entire device is not something that is realizable when spawning CNN type work from TF using cuDNN.